# Podio fields property is empty in Item object

Tags: php, podio

This has just started happening with no changes to our implementation.

When I query (it seems any item) the API is no longer returning data in the `fields` property.

```
PodioItem {#354 ▼
  -__attributes: array:32 [▼
    "item_id" => 1234567890
    "external_id" => null
    "title" => "INV-1234567890-Deposit"
    "link" => "[redacted]"
    "rights" => array:8 [▶]
    "created_on" => "2019-09-10 22:28:37"
    "app_item_id_formatted" => "1310"
    "app_item_id" => 1310
    "created_by" => PodioByLine {#362 ▶}
    "created_via" => PodioVia {#363 ▶}
    "initial_revision" => PodioItemRevision {#364 ▶}
    "current_revision" => PodioItemRevision {#367 ▶}
    "fields" => PodioVia {#370 ▼
      -__attributes: []
      -__belongs_to: array:2 [▶]
      -__properties: array:5 [▶]
      -__relationships: []
      #__id_column: null
    }
    "like_count" => null
    "is_liked" => false
    "ratings" => array:1 [▶]
    "user_ratings" => array:1 [▶]
    "last_event_on" => "2019-09-10 23:17:06"
    "participants" => []
    "tags" => []
    "refs" => []
    "linked_account_id" => null
    "subscribed" => false
    "invite" => []
    "app" => PodioApp {#371 ▶}
    "ref" => PodioReference {#372 ▶}
    "reminder" => PodioReminder {#373 ▶}
    "recurrence" => PodioRecurrence {#374 ▶}
    "linked_account_data" => PodioLinkedAccountData {#375 ▶}
    "comments" => PodioLinkedAccountData {#376 ▶}
    "revisions" => PodioVia {#392 ▶}
    "files" => PodioVia {#401 ▶}
  ]
  -__belongs_to: null
  -__properties: array:38 [▶]
  -__relationships: array:15 [▶]
  #__id_column: "item_id"
}
```

You can see `__attributes` are empty for `fields`. Again, for every item I have tested and for several apps, it is the same.

As I said nothing has changed in our implementation - last week it was working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you need to change implementation then, maybe these fields are exposed before, but then they changed something internally, which you can do nothing about, if they change something in their code, you have no choice but to adjust as well. maybe they also have this in their some sort of changelog and you need a specific method to get those. if you're unsure and you're paying them, **contact their support**

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I have already contacted them and they asked me to post here.